# How to stop default api vesion showing up in swagger document with NSwag in .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swashbuckle, nswag, api-versioning

After getting Api versioning fixed with following in .net core

```
            services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
            {
                options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                options.UseApiBehavior = false; //If true [ApiController] attribute required for versioning
            })
            .AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
            {
                options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
                options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
            });
```

next problem I faced was having default api version show up swagger document. As shown below image.
[image]

There are lot of articles to fix it using swashbuckle but how to get it fixed with NSwag?

Answer (score 2):

With NSwug we can use a DocumentProcessors which can be used to filter out the unwanted swagger paths.

I have used below nuget packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="5.0.0" /> 
<PackageReference Include="NSwag.AspNetCore" Version="13.9.4" />
```

Below shows how I registered them and fixed the problem

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            ....
            
            services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
            {
                options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            })
            .AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
            {
                options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
                options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
            });
            
            services.AddSwaggerDocument(config =>
            {
                SwaggerConfigure(config, "v1", true);
            });

            services.AddSwaggerDocument(config =>
            {
                SwaggerConfigure(config, "v2", false);
            });
    }
```

SwaggerConfigure implementation

```
        private void SwaggerConfigure(AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGeneratorSettings configure, string version, bool isDefaultVersion)
    {
        configure.DocumentName = version;
        configure.ApiGroupNames = new[] { version };

        if (isDefaultVersion)
        {
            configure.DocumentProcessors.Add(new RemoveVersionFromDefault(version));
        }

        configure.PostProcess = document =>
        {
            document.Info.Version = version;
            document.Info.Title = $"{GetApiTitle()} API";
        };

        configure.AllowNullableBodyParameters = false;
        configure.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    }
```

DocumentProcessor implementation

```
    public class RemoveVersionFromDefault : IDocumentProcessor
    {
    private readonly string _defaultVersion;

    public RemoveVersionFromDefault(string defaultVersion)
    {
        _defaultVersion = defaultVersion;
    }

    public void Process(DocumentProcessorContext context)
    {
        var keys = new List<string>();
        foreach (var (key, value) in context.Document.Paths)
        {
            if (key.Contains($"/{_defaultVersion}/"))
            {
                keys.Add(key);
            }
        }

        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            context.Document.Paths.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Thats it. Hope this will help someone who is looking for a similar solution with NSwug

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that this scenario can be solved. An alternative approach would be to create and register a custom **IApiDescriptionProvider** that is executed last. From the resultant **ApiDescription** instances provided to the context of `IApiDescriptionProvider.OnProvidersExecuted` you can then find what you're looking for and remove the descriptors from the results. In this scenario, you're looking to remove the descriptors that match the default API version with the API version parameter.

This approach has several benefits:

1. You can get the configured default API version by injecting `IOptions<ApiVersioningOptions>`
2. You can match the API version using the `ApiDescriptor.GetApiVersion` extension method and filter descriptors that still have the API version parameter. You can hardcode the name or get it from the injected `ApiVersioningOptions.RouteConstraintName` in step 1. No *magic string* parsing or matching.
3. If you switch between Open API (Swagger) document generators (e.g. NSwag to Swashbuckle or vice versa) no other code changes are required to address this scenario

> **Aside:** The comment regarding:
> `options.UseApiBehavior = false; //If true [ApiController] attribute required for versioning`
>
> isn't quite accurate. You're probably getting the results that you want, but there's more to the story. This behavior and customization isn't well-documented and hardly anyone changes it. The behavior is really controlled by [IApiControllerSpecification](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning/ApplicationModels/IApiControllerSpecification.cs) and [IApiControllerFilter](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning/ApplicationModels/IApiControllerFilter.cs). The default filter implementation just runs through all registered specifications so there is little reason to ever change it. Each specification defines whether a controller matches. There is an out-of-the-box specification that matches `[ApiController]`, but that isn't the only specification that exists (ex: OData controllers). The reason the `UseApiBehavior` option exists at all is because before `[ApiController]` (in 2.1 I *think*), there was no clear way to disambiguate between UI-only and API-only controllers. That really irked some developers who mixed both types of controllers. Conversely, flipping a hard switch to disable that potentially broke developers who wanted that behavior. Setting the value to `false` merely ignores all filtering and reverts back to the days before `[ApiController]` which was introduced in a feature enhancement called *API Behaviors*. The new design allows you to replace or create new specifications should you decide to do so. It may not apply to you, but it should be known that the configuration option is not a hard `on` or `off` for matching `[ApiController]` and other, more complex, controller filtering is possible.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for the input and comment. Really gives a lot of insight.

Comment: I found out that options.UseApiBehavior = false; affects the actual swagger document as it actually removed all api behaviours.
Instead I forced the apicontroller in assembly level as [assembly:ApiController] as mentioned  https://www.strathweb.com/2019/01/enabling-apicontroller-globally-in-asp-net-core-2-2/

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using Nswag, I was stuck into the issue and then with some search came up into investigating about the AddOperationFilter and solves the issue. Hope it helps someone!:)

```
settings.GeneratorSettings.AddOperationFilter(x =>
{
    if (x.Document.Paths == null) return true;
    var keysToRemove = x.Document.Paths
        .Where(kv => kv.Key.StartsWith("/api/"))
        .Select(kv => kv.Key)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
    {
        x.Document.Paths.Remove(key);
    }

    return true;
});
```